Pagination starts at the bottom instead of the top. How to fix?
I'm working on a Next.js application that has pagination.
My pagination links are at the bottom of the page. When I scroll to the bottom and click a new page, I stay at the bottom of the page. What I want is to start back up at the top of the page.
The Google AI says to do this:
import { useEffect } from 'react';
function YourComponent(){
    useEffect(()=>{
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }, []);
}

But that doesn't work. I have tried other variations of using window.scrollTo(x,y) and element.scrollIntoView() but nothing I do works.
How do I fix this?
I am using:

next v13.2.3 - with "traditional" pages routing
react v18.2.0


Should questions include "tags" in their titles? - FYI: Please note that Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned and read Help Center: AI policy. It is not permitted to use AI tools to generate or reword content that you post on Stack Overflow.

After more research, I have found a solution. My Google search criteria was this:
https://www.google.com/search?q=%40elastic%2Freact-search-ui+paging+starts+at+bottom+instead+of+top
Which brought up this result:
https://github.com/elastic/search-ui/issues/500
With this solution:
onSearch: async (state: RequestState,
    queryConfig: QueryConfig,
    next: (
        state: RequestState,
        queryConfig: QueryConfig
    ) => Promise<ResponseState>
) => {
    const response = await next(state, queryConfig);
    window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
    });
    return response;
},

Which worked beautifully!

Use next.js Link component it will automaticly scroll back at the start of page.
import Link from 'next/link';
<Link href={`?page=1`}>1</Link>

on the other hand if you want to do it using js
window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });

if you want to make that scroll smoother using css style html tag like.
html {
   scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

